# Make Y axis values show on subplots in pyplot

Tags: matplotlib

I have the following python code to plot a 2x2 set of graphs.
I would like to make the yaxis show its values on both columns (show Duration numbers on the right as well).

I am ok with the X axis being shown only for the lower row.
How can I do that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

builds = ['20191006.1','20191004.1']
totals_10t = [39671486, 39977577]
totals_1t = [9671486, 3977577]
means_10t = [96160,99630]
means_1t = [9160,9630]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True,sharey=False, squeeze=False)
fig.suptitle('perf results')
axs[0,0].plot(builds, totals_10t)
axs[0,0].set_title('10T Totals')
axs[0,1].plot(builds, totals_1t, 'tab:orange')
axs[0,1].set_title('1T Totals')
axs[0,1].set_ylabel('Duration(ms)')
axs[0,1].yaxis.tick_right()
axs[1,0].plot(builds, means_10t, 'tab:green')
axs[1,0].set_title('10T Means')
axs[1,1].plot(builds, means_1t, 'tab:red')
axs[1,1].set_title('1T Means')
axs[1,1].yaxis.tick_right()
axs[1,1].set_ylabel('Duration(ms)')

for ax in axs.flat:
        ax.set(xlabel='Build',ylabel='Duration(ms)')

for ax in axs.flat:
        ax.label_outer()

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with subplots]

Comment: `ax.label_outer()` <---- what happens if you remove this?

Comment: that worked! @PaulH please provide this as an answer so I could it mark it as such and you get the credit. thanks